# How to pass data from parrent constructor to child component in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, data-binding

I have a angular 2 page where i need to show 2 different components using same array of data from external API. Parent is regular component, and child is shared among several other components using same functionality.

In parent component class i have output property declared:

```
public weatherList: WeatherForecast[];
@Output() public weatherListData: any;
```

Inside constructor of parent component, i populate `weatherListData` property with data from an external API

```
    http.get(url)
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.weatherList= result.json() as WeatherForecast[];
            this.weatherListData = this.weatherList;
        });
```

and i'm using it inside parent template with success, something like: `{{ weatherList.someValue }}`

Also, inside parent component template, i have a call to a child component

```
<daily-temperature-chart [weatherListData]='weatherListData'></daily-temperature-chart>
```

In child component class i have declared property

```
@Input() weatherListData: any;
```

but, when i try to access `weatherListData` property in constructor, or init of child component, i get undefined result.

**EDIT**: I have played with console.log() and noticed that child component Constructor and OnInit() methods return before http.get() from parent component. Maybe this is problem, but i'm still new to angular and can't tell.

Can someone point me how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this without the `@Output` decorator? Because, that's not really what `@Output` is for.

Comment: Yes, but it's same.

Comment: Okay. And you are 100% certain that the `http.get` is returning an array, and not an object. I am wondering if the cast is failing.

Comment: I'm "console.log()" both weatherData and weatherListData inside http.get(), and they are identical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a service call so you can't go for constructor or OnInit because component initialization is not dependent on your service call for this situation angular provides `OnChanges` whenever your input value is updated OnChanges fired.

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: any){
  console.log(changes);
  console.log(this.weatherListData);
 }
```

OnChanges passes as well an argument which informs about the current state and pervious state now you are able to use input values. If your components are bases on input and input is based on any other operation you can handle it in this block.